# Problems with bool and if statemetns

Tags: c++, if-statement, boolean

I have a problem with some code I am trying to right in c++, it's the average of 3 test scores and the cout will give you your average but then it needs a bool variable if the average is equal to 100% then true it will display a string of "Congrats you received a perfect" and if it's not 100% nothing will appear besides their average, but I keep getting the string of "Congrats" to come up even if the average is not 100%

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()

{
int score1, score2, score3;
    cout << "Enter your 3 test scores and I will \n";
    cout << "average them: ";
    cin >> score1 >> score2 >> score3 ;
double average;
    average = (score1 + score2 + score3) / 3.0;
    cout << "Your average is " << average << endl;
    bool perfectScore;
    if(average = 100)
        perfectScore = true;
    else
        perfectScore = false;
    if(perfectScore == true)
        cout << "Congratulations! \n";
        cout << "That's a perfect score. \n";
        cout << "you deserve a pat on the back! \n";

        return 0;

}
```

Comment: `if(average = 100)` should be `if(average == 100)`

Comment: You should format your code properly.

Comment: That worked! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

use `if(average == 100)` (comparison) instead of `if(average = 100)` (assignment).

You may also should use a block.

```
if(perfectScore == true) { /* add { */
    cout << "Congratulations! \n";
    cout << "That's a perfect score. \n";
    cout << "you deserve a pat on the back! \n";
} /* add } */
```

Answer (score 0):

(EDIT: This is not an answer to solve your problem, it's simple advice)

Be careful when writing your if clauses,

```
if(perfectScore == true)
    cout << "Congratulations! \n";
    cout << "That's a perfect score. \n";
    cout << "you deserve a pat on the back! \n";

    return 0;
```

Perhaps you meant for all the cout lines to be in the body of this `if` but they are not. What you wrote is equivalent to this,

```
if(perfectScore == true) {
    cout << "Congratulations! \n";
}
cout << "That's a perfect score. \n";
cout << "you deserve a pat on the back! \n";

return 0;
```

Because, by default, if you don't include brackets the `if` will contain only the first statement that follows it. Even if you write one-liner `if`s it's never a bad thing to **always** explicitly write the brackets.

This how you should do it,

```
if(perfectScore == true) {
    cout << "Congratulations! \n";
    cout << "That's a perfect score. \n";
    cout << "you deserve a pat on the back! \n";
}
return 0;
```